# How to call a window using tabcontrol in wpf

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol

I have a **Main_window** which *runs as base.*

It has some buttons on its left side.

If button1 is clicked, I need a window ( which is defined separately as login) to open as a Tabcontrol in my Main_window (located at center).

So each time when I click one of the buttons, the corresponding windows should be shown as tabs in the main window.

Hoping for the right answer...
Thank You.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

XAML:

```
   <Window x:Class="Test1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="134*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="369*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Button Content="Login" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="24,28,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="1">
            <TabControl Name="TabControl"/>
         </Grid>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

C#:

```
namespace Test1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            TabItem item = new TabItem();
            item.Header = "Some header";
            //item.Content = < your content> 
            TabControl.Items.Add(item); 

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Ugur

But How can I call another form window1.xaml into this tabcontrol ?
I have designed window1.xaml seperately.

Comment: @irshadibrahim, you don't need a window. Please create some UserControl  like  MyUserControl1.xaml.  and   give it as the content of the tab item.